# c# create dynamic Class / Properties at runtime in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, list, reflection

These are the methods i need wrote:

```
List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
public List<Test> GetData(int ReportId)
     {
       StringBuilder qr = new StringBuilder();
       StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder();
       DataTable dt;

    qr.AppendLine(" select SQL");
    qr.AppendLine(" from  V_REPORT_SQL f");
    qr.AppendLine(String.Format(" where REPORT_ID = '{0}'", ReportId));

   dt = DataManager.GetDatadt(qr);
      foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
         {
           SQL.Append(dr[0].DBStr());
         }

        dt = DataManager.GetData(SQL);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
         {
        Test t = new Test()
        {
         can i dynamically create and iterate over the properties and assign the datarow? 
        };

        test.Add(t);
    }
    return test;

    }
```

//This is the DataContract

```
 [DataContract]
    public class Test
    {  
    }
```

**Table V_Report_SQL**

```
reportid | SQL
1        | select id,Name from table1
2        | select acctid,Name,date from table2
3        | select Name,location,date,XX,XX,XX from table3
```

the problem i am trying to solve is i am sending the reportid to get the sql dynamically and then i pass the sql and i get the data in DataTable. now i need to send it as `list<Test>`. Can i dynamically create properties for the class Test. 
for example :

```
     for report id 1

     [DataMember]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     for report id 2 

     [DataMember]
     public int acctid { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

the client application that consumes the service is build on silverlight 4.

Let me know if i am not clear, i can update it. I am not sure about the route i chose to solve. is there any other way i could solve this problem.

**Update:**

I have updated,I no longer use dynamic, not sure this route will solve.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a bad idea to try to use platform-specific types in a web service. For example, you wouldn't expect Java to understand the `DataTable` type.

I suspect you will have the same problem trying to return a `dynamic` object. This can't even be described by the WSDL of the service, so I doubt any caller would know what to do with such a return value.

In fact, I don't know how the service would even serialize such a thing.

Comment: is there any other way i could solve the problem without using dynamic

Comment: I don't see that your schema is dynamic. Doesn't your SQL always return the same columns with the same types?

Comment: no it might have any number of columns with different datatype.

Answer (score 1):

I think your intentions are noble but effectively you would create a constantly changing web service. Who would use it? If I were you I would return one of the following objects:

1. 2D table of strings (first row would be a series of headers and the
   remaining ones would store values respectively)
2. 1D table of strings (property name - property value pairs)
3. A string (flat content of a CSV file)
4. Binary CSV
5. Dynamic XML that you'll have to crawl through on the client side

I obviously might be wrong assuming that you care about the textual values only, but since you are using a report table, I thought there is a fair chance that this is the case.

Hope this helps,
Piotr

Comment: i am thinking to send through dynamic xml.

Comment: If you're going to go ahead with this idea, please also consider exposing XSD documents for your dynamic XMLs or just one generic one applicable for all your returned XMLs.